# iconv fails when converting from ANSI to UTF-8

Tags: bash, unix, shell, shell-script, csv

Im using a Shell Script to convert a file's encoding from ANSI to UTF-8. I am using this command:

```
iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" $csvname -o $mobcsvname
```

Here, the csvname and mobcsvname are variable to store the input and output filenames.
The script runs without any error but the output file stays the same encoding as the original file i.e. ANSI.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide more context. How do you call this command line? Do the paths perhaps contain spaces? They aren’t quoted! Oh yeah, and does the input file actually contain anything that would make the output file different? ASCII characters translate 1:1 to UTF-8!

Comment: @DanielB Hi Daniel, I have created a .sh file containing this code and executing the script by `sh filename.sh`. This script should convert the input file's encoding from ANSI to UTF-8. The input file is a .csv file (ANSI), containing a lot of characters and it is impossible to verify if there would be any visible character changes. I am verifying the file encoding from Notepad++.

Comment: Just search for any byte values larger than 127 (using your favorite hex editor or whatever). If there aren't and a BOM is not added, the conversion won't change anything and this is correct.

Comment: @DanielB Can you please elaborate a bit more how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 has variable-length characters. Some are one byte, some two etc. All ASCII characters (originally 7-bit, ranging from 0..127) are encoded with one byte. This means a file containing

> Hello World

in just about any western encoding *is already valid UTF-8*. Even if you try to convert it, the output will be *the same*. `iconv` *will not* add a byte-order mark.

Of course, were the file to contain, say

> Motoröl

it would *not* be valid UTF-8 yet.

Notepad++ is, by default, very pessimistic: Unless it encounters a byte-order mark at the beginning of the file or maybe any byte sequences that look like UTF-8, it treats the file as non-UTF-8.

This behavior can be changed under Settings → Preferences → New Document → Encoding. Check “Apply to opened ANSI files”.

To check whether your file actually has any characters that will change, use the following Python 3 script:

```
#!/bin/env python3

with open("INSERT FILE NAME HERE", "rb") as f:
   while 1:
      byte_s = f.read(1)
      if not byte_s:
         break
      byte = byte_s[0]
      if byte > 127:
         print("Got extended ASCII character")
```

It will read your file byte per byte and check whether any byte is larger than 127. If there isn’t any, then again: *Your file is already valid UTF-8.*